# Redirecting many times laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-8

I have encountered a lot of this error. but I can't understand why that doesn't work??
Here is the scenario: I want to make a middleware to prevent authenticated users from viewing the login and register form.
So, I already wrote the MustNotBeLoggedIn.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateUsers;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MustNotBeLoggedIn
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('user')) {
            return redirect()->route('not_allowed');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and here is web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'authenticate', 'middleware' => 'check.MustNotBeLoggedIn'], function () {
        // Login / Register Form
        Route::view('/login-register', 'authentication.login_register')->name('authenticate.login-register');

        // Login, Register, Logout
        Route::post('/login', [LoginAndRegisterController::class, 'login'])->name('authenticate.validate');
        Route::post('/register', [LoginAndRegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('authenticate.new');
        Route::post('/logout', [LoginAndRegisterController::class, 'logout'])->name('authenticate.logout');

        // Forget Password
        Route::view('/forget-password', 'authentication.forget_password')->name('authenticate.forget_password');
        Route::get('/password-reset/{token}', function ($token) {
            return view('authentication.reset_password', ['token' => $token]);
        })->name('password.reset');
        Route::post('/send-reset-link', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'requestLink'])->name('authenticate.send_reset_link');
        Route::post('/reset', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'resetPassword'])->name('authenticate.reset_password');
    });
```

and I registered the middleware in the kernel.php
`'check.MustNotBeLoggedIn' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateUsers\MustBeLoggedIn::class,`

one last notice: The view not allowed hasn't any middlewares

```
Route::view('/not_found', 'errors.404')->name('not_allowed');
```

Comment: Check if your route 'not_allowed' is not under some other middleware that redirects to login.

Comment: In the register line, `MustBeLoggedIn` should be `MustNotBeLoggedIn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the login and register routes are not suppose to be in the authenticated route group, try this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'authenticate', 'middleware' => 'check.MustNotBeLoggedIn'], function () {
    
    Route::post('/logout', [LoginAndRegisterController::class, 'logout'])->name('authenticate.logout');

    // Forget Password
    Route::view('/forget-password', 'authentication.forget_password')->name('authenticate.forget_password');
    Route::get('/password-reset/{token}', function ($token) {
        return view('authentication.reset_password', ['token' => $token]);
    })->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('/send-reset-link', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'requestLink'])->name('authenticate.send_reset_link');
    Route::post('/reset', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'resetPassword'])->name('authenticate.reset_password');
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest'], function() {
// Login / Register Form
        Route::view('/login-register', 'authentication.login_register')->name('authenticate.login-register');

    // Login, Register, Logout
    Route::post('/login', [LoginAndRegisterController::class, 'login'])->name('authenticate.validate');
    Route::post('/register', [LoginAndRegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('authenticate.new');
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but, where does the guest middleware redirect if the user is already authenticated?

Comment: I deleted my middleware check.MustNotBeLoggedIn and replaced it with guest. It just worked fine....

Comment: it will redirect authenticated users to the home page or dashboard as the case maybe, it ensures that only un-authenticated users can view the login and register page.